# Nav Menu not showing on Ipad Portrait

Tags: css, ipad, breakpoints, nav, portrait

I am having a CSS/Nav issue....

On iPad portrait the menu isn't showing.

I have attached a screenshot which shows 767px shot at top and 768px shot at bottom and as you can see it dissappears at this width...I can't seem to figure out why...The site is: http://bargdvd.co.uk  I have tried reducing menu items and that doesn't work.  It is a child theme based on Louis WP theme.

[image]

Any ideas greatly appreciated.
many thanks in advance

Comment: Adjust top css on line no 1269 in style.css

Comment: Thanks, if I adjust that though it is then in the wrong place when the screen decreases to 767px :/

Comment: add media css between 768px to 1024px

Answer (score 0):

Look at style.css line 1268.

`@media all and (max-width: 768px)`